# PCB Layout: Variant A, B or C

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, design, layout

I've just started dabbling with hardware design and I'm a little confused.

Which one of the following variants for the battery protection circuit is the most optimal one? I've been trying to follow the best PCB guidelines, but eh...a few pointers would be greatly appreciated.

## Circuit

[image: Circuit]

## Variant A

[image: Variant A]

## Variant B

[image: Variant B]

## Variant C

[image: Variant C]

## DW01 Datasheet

[image: DW01 Datasheet]
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/2/5/1/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you show designators, i.e. which component is which?

Comment: also, variant A, but simply route `BP_OC` in the middle below the components. No need for any layer crossing.s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative, using no via's

[image]